# What's causing my Bootstrap col to have large top 'margin' at medium breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ged47t3u/1/

This may be a `position: absolute;` issue.

I have a 'col-md-8' with 2 elements. The first is stting atop the 2nd and has position: absolute and z-indexapplied. The 2nd element has a large margin-top. The desired effect is the first element sits over half of the 2nd element, see image:

[image: > 992px]

This works fine, until the screen size reaches Bootstraps Medium break point `@media (max-width: 992px)`. At that point the red element gets pushed down into the green.

[image: < 992px]

I cannot see any css changes to the elements in inspector. This has got me stumped. I can apply a negative `top` value at that breakpoint but it doesnt seem right.

Would anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: Do you actually need to use a column for this because its `float` is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the behavior is caused by this Bootstrap style:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9 {
    float: left;
}
```

I'm guessing the `float` value is causing the element to collapse with the `.content` element's margin. When the float is removed, the margin collapse is gone.

From MDN's [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing):

> Parent and first/last child
>   If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Comment: Damn, you're right! No way to really overwrite this. I've had to use a negative margin-top on the #header element

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `position:absolute;` in `.content` like the code below?

```
.content {
width: 100%;
background-color: green;
height: 300px;
margin-top: 110px;
position:absolute; // this
}
```

Comment: Works until you have subsequent content bellow:  https://jsfiddle.net/ged47t3u/4/